# return ip of a server by python scipt running on it.?

Tags: python, linux

i ma creating a server monitoring tool , which will be installed on any machine and that will provide server statics. i have created a script that can be deployed on any machine and can print server statics for that machine.
my task here is to detect from which machine the output came.
how can i do that plese help.
i have used following python command.

```
import socket
socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
```

but this return only ip .i want all server parameters ,like public dns, private dns, location  name,dns ,hostname ,private_dns, public_dns .

Comment: Try this response in other question:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/8797477/1171280

Comment: thanks @AlbertoMegía ,this is giving me only host name and ip address, i want all other parameters as mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 0):

```
import platform 
platform.node()
```

may help

There are some clues [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271740/how-can-i-use-python-to-get-the-system-name) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271740/how-can-i-use-python-to-get-the-system-name)